# Snort error on FreeBSD-9: Unknown preprocessor "ftp_telnet"

Tags: unix, freebsd, snort

I've installed "Snort" on FreeBSD-9.1 (32-bit) from the standard ports using:

```
pkg_add -r snort
```

After configuring and running with:

```
snort -c /etc/snort/snort.conf -A full -u snort -g snort -i em1 -T
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR: /etc/snort/snort.conf(337) Unknown preprocessor: "ftp_telnet".
```

Doing some search on the Internet, the only thing I found is that this could happen if I'm using a `snort.conf` with a different version from snort itself, but this is not my case. My snort version is:

```
 ,,_     -*> Snort! <*-
o"  )~   Version 2.9.3.1 IPv6 GRE (Build 40) 
 ''''    By Martin Roesch & The Snort Team: http://www.snort.org/snort/snort-team
         Copyright (C) 1998-2012 Sourcefire, Inc., et al.
         Using libpcap version 1.3.0
         Using PCRE version: 8.31 2012-07-06
         Using ZLIB version: 1.2.7
```

and I'm using `snortrules-snapshot-2931.tar.gz` from [snort.org](http://www.snort.org).

I've had some previous experience installing and running snort on Linux and I never faced such errors, but I'm fairly new to BSD-UNIX.

Comment: No one answered this question in a long time, and all my attempts failed to solve it and the importance of this has now passed for me ... But for anyone else who might face this issue, I think the cause of the problem is that I installed Snort from the ports ... I haven't tried it yet but my best guess is that if I try and install this from source, this problem won't show up ... So, in short: Try installing Snort from source and not from the ports.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like "make install" didn't create the necessary sym links in

```
/usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor
```

Do the following and see if it fixes it.

```
cd /usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor

ln -s libsf_ftptelnet_preproc.so.0.0 libsf_ftptelnet_preproc.so
ln -s libsf_dcerpc_preproc.so.0.0 libsf_dcerpc_preproc.so
ln -s libsf_smtp_preproc.so.0.0 libsf_smtp_preproc.so
ln -s libsf_dns_preproc.so.0.0 libsf_dns_preproc.so
ln -s libsf_ssh_preproc.so.0.0 libsf_ssh_preproc.so
```

Answer (score 0):

No one answered this question in a long time, and all my attempts failed to solve it and the importance of this has now passed for me ... But for anyone else who might face this issue, I think the cause of the problem is that I installed Snort from the ports ... I haven't tried it yet but my best guess is that if I try and install this from source, this problem won't show up.

So, in short: **Try installing Snort from source and not from the ports.**
Here is a useful link on installing Snort from source on FreeBSD-9:

- **[Install Snort 2.9.6.0 on FreeBSD 9.0](http://s3.amazonaws.com/snort-org/www/assets/207/snort296x_freebsd9x.pdf)**

Answer (score 0):

On CentOS7 I see same error, I found this line isn't correct `dynamicpreprocessor directory /usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor/` the correct path is `dynamicpreprocessor directory /usr/lib64/snort-2.9.8.3_dynamicpreprocessor/`   and

```
# path to base preprocessor engine
dynamicengine /usr/local/lib64/snort-2.9.8.3_dynamicengine/libsf_engine.so
```